# Is there a way to find the n most distant vectors in an array?

Tags: python, vector, cluster-analysis, doc2vec, dimensionality-reduction

I have an array of thousands of doc2vec vectors with 90 dimensions. For my current purposes I would like to find a way to "sample" the different regions of this vector space, to get a sense of the diversity of the corpus. For example, I would like to partition my space into n regions, and get the most relevant word vectors for each of these regions.

I've tried clustering with hdbscan (after reducing the dimensionality with UMAP) to carve the vector space at its natural joints, but it really doesn't work well.

So now I'm wondering whether there is a way to sample the "far out regions" of the space (n vectors that are most distant from each other).

1. Would that be a good strategy?
2. How could I do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't a random sample from all vectors necessarily encounter any of the various 'regions' in the set?

If there are "natural joints" and clusters to the documents, some clustering algorithm should be able to find the N clusters, then the smaller number of NxN distances between each cluster's centroid to each other cluster's centroid might identify those "furthest out" clusters.

Note for any vector, you can use the `Doc2Vec` doc-vectors `most_similar()` with a `topn` value of `0`/false-ish to get the (unsorted) similarities to *all* other model doc-vectors. You could then find the least-similar vectors in that set. If your dataset is small enough for it to be practical to do this for "all" (or some large sampling) of doc-vectors, then perhaps other docs that appear in the "bottom N" least-similar, for the most number of other vectors, would be the most "far out".

Whether this idea of "far out" is actually shown in the data, or useful, isn't clear. (In high-dimensional spaces, everything can be quite "far" from everything else in ways that don't match our 2d/3d intuitions, and slight differences in some vectors being a little "further" might not correspond to useful distinctions.)

Comment: Thanks a lot gojomo, that's very helpful. I have a few follow-up questions if you don't mind.

My models have around 15,000 documents, and 40 and 90 dimensions respectively.

1. What would you say is the best way to find clusters of documents within a Doc2Vec model? (a) Is it better to perform some dimensionality reduction first (and if so, is umap better than t-sne?), (b) what clustering algorithm would work best? When I reduce the dimensionality with t-sne or umap, I get a big lump of docs with no clear boundaries.

Comment: 2. Aside from clustering, what would be the best way to sample the topics discussed in the corpus? My particular corpus contains descriptions of subjective experience, and I want to map out the "state space" of these experiences, i.e. get a sense of the diversity of subjective experiences described in the corpus. For this I was wondering whether I could get n vectors that evenly partition the space, and get the most similar word vectors to each of these vectors. Should I do that, and if so get I do it with gensim? Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: I've only done supervised-classification-with-known-labels with `Doc2Vec` vectors, not unsupervised clustering, so can't recommend any particular clustering approach. Many should work, & then seeing which docs have neighbors-in-other-clusters may be informative. You may want to avoid collapsing any cluster down to a single centroid, as it may hide certain "shapes" of relationships in high-dimensions. And seeing a "big lump" in low-dimensional projection may be a limitation of a particular projection/clustering - the clusters might still be useful other ways or improvable via tuning the steps.

Comment: Many thanks gojomo! I ended up using spherical kmeans clustering (using cosine distance) on the vectors without dimensionality reduction. It actually worked pretty well, so thank you! I'll follow your advice regarding centroids.